# Unwanted value changes in 1D and 2D arrays returning a value from a function in c++ code

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a multi-file program that reads data from a file and stores the values in various arrays. The size of the arrays is not known during the compiling. After the values are stored, I use another function to determine the maximum and minimum of each array and return the max/min. Before the "return maximum" statement, the values in the array are correct. After "return maximum", the values are changed or erased.

Here is some of the code including one of the 2D arrays and one of the 1D arrays (there are a few more of those but I removed them so there's less code for you to look at)

**EDITED:

FunctionValues.h: ** removed destructor block

```
    class FunctionValues
    {
        //define variables, set up arrays of unknown size
        public:
            float **xvel;
            int *imax;
            int vessels;
            int tot_gridpt;
        public:
            //Constructor -- initialization of an object performed here
            FunctionValues(): xvel(NULL), imax(NULL) {}
            //Destructor
            ~FunctionValues() {
            }

            void read_function(string filename); 
    };
```

FunctionValues.cpp: (this reads a file with some imax values, vessel numbers and velocities and stores them in the appropriate arrays, the other includes are also there) All the arrays made are stored in FunctionValues myval object

```
    #include "FunctionValues.h"

    using namespace std;

    void FunctionValues::read_function(string filename)
    {
        std::ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
        //acquire variables
        myfile >> vessels; //number of vessels
        imax = new int[vessels];
    //... code reading the file and storing them, then imax and some other values are multiplied to get int tot_gridpt
        xvel = new float *[vessels];
        for (int i = 0; i < vessels; i++)
        {
            xvel[i] = new float[tot_gridpt];
        }
    //arrays filled 
        for (int i = 0; i < limiter; i++)
        {
            myfile >> xvel[count][i];
        }
    }
```

Gridpts.cpp:  ** range() arguments and parameters

```
    #include "FunctionValues.h"
    #include "Gridpts.h"

    using namespace std;

        // forward declarations 
        float range(float **velocities, const FunctionValues *myval, int num);

    void Gridpts::create_grid(FunctionValues *myval, int ptsnum)
    {
        //find range, 1 for max, 0 for min from smooth wall simulation results rounded to the nearest integer
        float maximum = range(myval->xvel, &myval, 1);
        float minimum = range(myval->xvel, &myval, 0);
    }
```

range.cpp: ** arguments changed to pass by pointer

```
    float range(float **velocities, const FunctionValues *myval, int num)
     {
        if (num == 1) 
        {
            float maximum = 0;
            for (int round = 0; round < myval->vessels; round++)
            {
                for (int count = 0; count < myval->tot_gridpt; count++)
                {
                    if (velocities[round][count] > maximum)
                    {
                        maximum = velocities[round][count];
                    }
                }
            }
            maximum = ceil(maximum);
            return maximum;
        }
```

main.cpp:

```
        corner_pts.create_grid(&myval, ptsnum);
```

This is where the error occurs. cout << "CHECKPOINT: " << myval.xvel[0][0] before "return maximum;" gives -0.39032 which is correct. After "return maximum", causes nothing to be printed and then the program crashes when trying run range() again using the xvel array. Similarly for myval.imax[0].

I apologize for copying in so much code. I tried to only include the essential to what is happening with the array. I have only started programming for about a month so I'm sure this is not the most efficient way to write code but I would greatly appreciate any insight as to why the arrays are being changed after returning a float. Thank you in advance for your time. (And if I have broken any rule about posting format, please let me know!)

Comment: there does not seem any problem , at least with this code snippet.

Comment: `float range(float **velocities, FunctionValues myval, int num);` You are calling the function where a copy of the object `myval` is created and used inside the function. Your *class definition* lacks the **Copy Contructor or Assignment Operator**. You need to define those operators.

Comment: @DOOM I added a comment to the answer below me but would this still be an issue because I do have the #include "FunctionValues.h" for range.cpp so I thought myval should not be destroyed at the end of range.cpp

Comment: As soon as I saw the raw pointers in the class for pointing to the array data, I knew the problem would due to not following the rule-of-three (or four or whatever people call it today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your program crashes when you call `range()` the second time. Therefore, your issue is most likely there.

Your program is crashing because you are taking your `FunctionValues` parameter by value, which is then destroyed at the end of the scope of the function, since it is local to the function.

```
// issue with myval being taken as a copy
float range(float **velocities, FunctionValues myval, int num)
{
    //...
} // destructor for local function arguments are called, including myval's destructor
```

**Explanation**

Your function parameter `FunctionValues myval` is taken by copy. Since you have no copy constructor defined, this means that the default copy behavior is used. The default copy behavior simply copies the object data from the supplied argument at the call site.

For pointers, since they hold addresses, this means that you are copying the addresses of those pointers into an object local to the `range()` function.\

Since `myval` is local to the `range()` function, its destructor is called at the end of the scope of the function. You are left with dangling pointers; pointers holding the memory addresses of memory that you have already given back to the free store.

Simplified example of your error:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
    X() : p{ new int{ 0 } }
    {
    }

    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting!" << std::endl; // A
        delete p;                              // B
    }

private:
    int* p;
};

void func(X param_by_value)                    // C
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    X x;                                       // D
    func(x);                                   // E
    func(x);                                   // F
}
```

1. You have variable `x` (**D**). You use it to call the function `func()` (**E**).
2. `func()` takes a parameter of type `X` by value, for which the variable name is `param_by_value` (**C**).
3. The data of `x` is copied onto `param_by_value`. Since `param_by_value` is local to `func()`, its destructor is called at the end of `func()`.
4. Both `x` and `param_by_value` have an `int*` data member called `p` that holds the same address, because of **3.**.
5. When `param_by_value`'s destructor is called, we call `delete` on `param_by_value`'s `p` (**B**), but `x`'s `p` still holds the address that was deleted.
6. You call `func()` again, this time the same steps are repeated. `x` is copied onto `param_by_value`. However, this time around, you try to use memory that has been given back to the free store (by calling delete on the address) and (luckily) get an error. Worse yet, when `main()` exits, it will attempt to call `x`'s destructor again.

You need to do some research into function parameters in C++. Passing by value, passing by reference, passing by pointer, and all of those combined with `const`.

As user @MichaelBurr points out, you should also look up the rule of three (and rule of five).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify: you are saying that FunctionValues myval is being destroyed because it is now a local variable. 

I didn't include it in my pasted code above, but range.cpp also has a #include "FunctionValues.h" at the top so shouldn't FunctionValues myval have a scope beyond range() and not be destroyed?

Comment: Including your header file doesn't have anything to do with the issue. The myval you use at the call site and the myval that is a function parameter in range() are separate entities. The problem is that because you are taking myval by value in range(), which copies the data of myval used at the call site. However, since the myval in range() is local to the function, its destructor gets called. Which calls delete on all the pointers, but you still have their address in the myval from the call site, which you try to use again after those pointers have been deleted.

Comment: Look up rule of three. If you class is managing raw pointers it needs to properly handle or disable several ways of copying those objects. C++11 provides additional tools for managing this kind of scenario including explicitly disabling constructors or improved smart pointers.

Comment: Thank you, and @Michael Burr, for your explanations. I looked up the various ways of passing by value/reference/pointer and it seems I should be passing things by const pointer instead of by value. When I pass things not by value then it creates/allocates memory for a copy of what the values stored in the addresses of the original pointers which can be destroyed without affecting the original values?

Comment: I've tried: `float maximum = range(myval->xvel, &myval, 1);` in Gridpts.cpp to pass these parameters into `float range(float **velocities, const FunctionValues *myval, int num) {...}` . This gives compiling errors though so I'm probably mixing up some of the syntax up.

Comment: @jwong: if you pass by reference (or pass a pointer to an object) then no additional object gets created/copied/allocated.  If you pass by value then the parameter in the function is a new object that is a copy of the object that was passed as an argument in the function call.  If your class manages raw pointers, then it must ensure that copy/assigment/delete funcitons are implemented properly (or are disabled).

Comment: @jwong Comment out FunctionValue's destructor code (leave an empty body) and see if your error still happens. It shouldn't. If there are other errors, then it's a different issue.

Comment: @bku_drytt The error is with the second argument (int num) of range in converting FunctionValues** to const FunctionValues*. This error persists even after removing the destructor and doesn't seem to make sense in general since it has nothing to due with int num. I figure there's probably an error earlier on.

Comment: @bku_drytt Why would I remove the destructor from FunctionValues.h? Just to summarize:
1) FunctionValues myval is created which points to addresses that contain array values
2) I submit a reference/addresses to myval (&myval) as a parameter to range().
3) range()'s 1st argument *myval points to this reference so *myval and the original myval are still occupying the same memory space? That seems different from what I got from [link](https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/12/the-rule-of-the-big-three-and-a-half-resource-management-in-c/)
4) *myval is destroyed at the end of range()
5) myval should remain

Comment: @jwong I wasn't telling you to remove the destructor, just to comment its body out and test so that you could see that deleting the pointers was causing your error. You need to post a new question with your new code or edit your original question. It's hard to help you without having the code.

Comment: @bku_drytt Sorry, I meant that I left the destructor block empty. Code edited in the question.

Comment: Replace range(myval->xvel, &myval, 1); with range(myval->xvel, myval, 1); as well as the other call to range(). Are you sure the new code you've edited compiles? By sending &myval, where myval is a pointer, you are sending the address of a pointer to your function (which is held in a pointer to pointer in this case).

Comment: @bku_drytt You're right! I got confused at what was being passed. The correct values of range() are being returned now. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain things to me, I will definitely have to do more careful readings on passing parameters so that I fully understand and am prepared for the next code I write. You're amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering why you opted not to use functionality like std::max/min_element in  and std::valarray/vector to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory?

Worse case scenario, if you're a fan of the explicit nature of 2d arrays x[a][b] you could create a basic matrix:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::valarray<int>& dims) : dims(dims) {}
    Matrix(std::valarray<int>& dims, std::valarray<T>& data) : dims(dims), data(data) {}
    std::Matrix<T> Matrix::operator[](int i) {
        auto newDims = std::valarray<int>(dims[1], dims.size() - 1);
        auto stride = std::accumulate(std::begin(newDims), std::begin(newDims) + newDims.size(), 1, [](int a, int b){ return a * b; })
        auto newData = std::valarray<T>(data[i * stride], data.size() - (i * stride));
        return Matrix<T>(newDims, newData);
    }
protected:
    std::valarray<T> data;
    std::valarray<int> dims;

}
```

I think more reliance on the standard libraries for their correctness will likely solve any memory access/integrity issues.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I didn't use max/min_element or valarray/vector mainly because I didn't know about them when I first wrote the code. I had only read through basic tutorials so I did know about for-loops and the like and the dynamic arrays were advice from a colleague. I will have to read up more on them to understand how they work.

Comment: @jwong No worries! Also take a look at smart pointers in c++, they're extremely useful and a good practice to use.